# Let $f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases} 0 & -1\leq x\leq0\\ x^4 & 0<x\leq1 \end{cases}$. In the taylor's formula for x=0 with maximum possible value of n

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> **Question** Let $f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
> 0 &\text{if } {-}1\leq x\leq0\\
> x^4 &\text{if } 0<x\leq1
> \end{cases}$. If $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}$$\frac{f^{(k)}\left(0\right)}{k!}x^{k}+\frac{f^{(n+1)}\left(\xi\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}x^{n+1}$
>   is the Taylor's formula for $f$ about $x=0$ with maximum possible value of $n$, then the value of $\xi$  for $0 <x\leq1$ is?

**I know** [image]

**I don't know how to apply the theorem on this question**

**Any and all help will be appreciated**

Comment: none of the derivatives of $f$ exist at $x=0$!

Comment: Does it means conditions for Taylor theorem is not fulfilled?

Comment: read the statements of the theorem carefully I am not able to see your images

Comment: Is $f(x) = x^4$ or $f(x) = x$ for any $0 < x \leq 1$? There is a contradiction between your title and your image. Which is the right one?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco That's why i added the question picture from the book.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Image is right ,It is just a typo

Comment: Ok, I edit your question to fix the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us find the value of $n$. Your function $f$ is only 3 times differentiable at $x = 0$, because
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } {-}1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
4x^3 &\text{if } 0 < x < 1
\end{cases}
&
f''(x) &= 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } {-}1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
12x^2 &\text{if } 0 < x < 1
\end{cases}
&
f'''(x) &= 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } {-}1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
24x &\text{if } 0 < x < 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and clearly $f'''$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.
Therefore, $n = 2$ (it is the maximum value for which the Taylor formula in the OP is well-defined). Note that $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$.

So, the Taylor formula for $f$ about $x = 0$ (more precisely, for all $0 < x \leq 1$) is:
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(0) + \frac{f'(0)}{1}x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac{f'''(\xi)}{6}x^3 = 4 \,\xi\, x^3
\end{align}
where $0 < \xi < 1$. Since $f(x) = x^4$ for all $ 0 < x \leq 1$, then $$\xi = \frac{x}{4}  \ .$$ Note that the condition $0 < \xi < 1$ is fulfilled by the above solution.